# Azure B2C reset password via graph api sdk

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

Can I reset a person's password using Azure B2C, Client Credential authentication and Graph API?

I'm trying, as shown below, but I'm getting an error.

Error: the user is not authorized to access this resource.

[image]

Comment: Note that, client credentials flow works with permissions of `Application` type only. Resetting password operation does not support `Application` permissions. You can check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I registered one Azure AD B2C application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I assigned **User Administrator** role to that application like this:

[image]

When I ran below c# code to reset B2C user's password using client credentials flow, I got **same error** even after assigning **User Administrator** role:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Authentication.Methods.Item.ResetPassword.ResetPasswordPostRequestBody
    {
        NewPassword = "xxxxxx",
    };
    var result = await graphClient.Users["userId"].Authentication.Methods["28c10230-6103-485e-b985-444c60001490"].ResetPassword.PostAsync(requestBody);

    Console.WriteLine("Password changed successfully!");
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, **client credentials** flow works with permissions of
> `Application` type only. Resetting password operation **does not**
> support `Application` permissions as mentioned in this [**MS Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions).
>
> Alternatively, you can run **Update user** query to reset B2C user's
> password by updating **`passwordProfile`** property.

When I ran below c# code by running `PATCH` query, user's password changed successfully with below response:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var requestBody = new User
    {
        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
        {
            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
            Password = "xxxxxxxxx",
        },
    };
    var result = await graphClient.Users["userId"].PatchAsync(requestBody);

    Console.WriteLine("Password changed successfully!");
}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, change your code to run `PATCH` query by updating  **`passwordProfile`** property along with assigning **User administrator** role to the application.

**Reference:**
[Update user - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-3-update-the-passwordprofile-of-a-user-to-reset-their-password)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations?tabs=applications#code-sample-how-to-programmatically-manage-user-accounts):

**Note**

For the application to update user account passwords, you'll need to grant the user administrator role to the application.